# TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSubstation' of undefined when trying to access function onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written the following code in Reactjs to display a list of elements from an array called "data" from a file called `"regionData"`. I am trying to make the buttons displayed be clickable and then display the message `"Button Clicked"` on the console but I keep getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSubstation' of undefined.

```
constructor (props) {
    super();
    this.showSubstation = this.showSubstation.bind(this)
}   

showSubstation = () => {
    console.log('Button Clicked');
};          

render() {
    return (
        <ul>
            {regionData.data.map(function(name, i){
                return <tr><button onClick={ () => {this.showSubstation}}>{regionData.data[i].name}</button></tr>
            })}
        </ul>      
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your component context (`this`) isn't exposed to your function inside the `map` call. You should use an `arrow function` instead, like below:

```
render(){
    return (
        <ul>       
          {regionData.data.map((name, i)=>{
            return <tr>
                      <button onClick={ () => {this.showSubstation}}> 
                            {regionData.data[i].name}
                      </button>
                   </tr>
          })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this initially, but I just got a syntax error when I added the => to the map function.

Comment: What kind of syntax error? which line? did you have the traceback?

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected { (34:42), this is the line where I added the =>(where the map function is called)

Comment: you need to remove the `function`. You did `function () => {}`, but you should use just `() => {}`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a normal function to `map`, which will be called without context, and therefore have undefined `this`.

```
render() {
    return (
        <ul>
            {regionData.data.map(function(name, i){ // <-- this function has undefined this
                //which is in turn captured by the arrow function that is created inside:
                return <tr><button onClick={ () => {this.showSubstation}}>{regionData.data[i].name}</button></tr>
            })}
        </ul>      
    );
}
```

One solution is to pass `this` as second parameter to `map`, which will then pass it on to the callback. Another is to use an arrow function as parameter for `map` aswell, which has lexical this and therefore keeps the proper context.

Another thing to note is that `this.showSubstation.bind(this)` is useless. `showSubStation` is an arrow function, and those will ignore bound `this` and obtain `this` lexically regardless.